# Getting version of Sqlite database

Tags: java, sqlite, sqlitejdbc

I am using the sqliteJDBC library (SqliteDriver) in my Java desktop application to hook to my sqlite database.

Is there a way I can get the version of the database? This way I can know if I need to add missing tables  based on the current database version

Thank you

PS: I am coming from android world where you can get the current version and "upgrade database". So I am assuming the database version is embedded in the db file/schema somewhere and can be queried

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Android framework, the database version is just the value set with [PRAGMA user_version](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_schema_version).

Comment: Does this exist in the database that I open with sqlite JDBC driver on Java J2se? Not Android

Comment: Did you see where the link goes to?

Comment: Yes the link goes to sqlite, but you said "in Android Framework" so that made me think if thats not accessable in Java framework, otherwise why mentioning android frame works

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with openhelper, check here
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html

Comment: I am talking about pure Java J2SE.. I know android :)